# Combined usage of HTML5 section elements and ARIA roles

Tags: html, accessibility, semantics, wai-aria

It's 2019 and, unfortunately, some of us still have to provide support for older versions of IE. (Insert rant here).
Years ago, we determined that for wider support we would use the seemingly redundant combination of HTML5 elements with the ARIA role, for example:

`<nav role="navigation"></nav>`

We've researched the topic again and nothing conclusive seems to have surfaced in terms of greater general accessibility support for HTML5 elements or even a comprehensive document on screen reader support.

IE includes only partial [support for HTML5 section elements](https://www.html5accessibility.com/#support).

This post shows some [screen reader support](https://tink.uk/screen-reader-support-for-html5-sections/) results from 2013.

Even [W3C still advises](https://www.w3.org/WAI/GL/wiki/Using_HTML5_nav_element#Example%3AThe_.3Cnav.3E_element) to use both until "support for HTML5 improves".

Yes, like me, you may be thinking it is absolutely redundant but there are still many sources indicating the combined usage of HTML5 elements and the role attribute is best for greater support. Does anyone have some clear information on the current state of this matter?

Comment: I was wishing for a [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/) for screenreader/browser combinations, too. Maybe we should start it? (:

Comment: note that the w3c url that you provided that advises using the role until support for html5 improves is 5 years old (!)  there have been lots of improvements over the past 5 years. the official spec for the <nav> element (https://www.w3.org/TR/html53/sections.html#the-nav-element) says the default role is "navigation" and to **do not set**.  so if the role of that element isn't being properly conveyed to assistive technology, then the browser has a bug.

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge, the `<nav>` element should correctly translate to a landmark role of `navigation` in Internet Explorer 9 and higher. It's only IE 8 and below that require the addition of `role="landmark"`. It's worth noting that the W3C article you referenced was last updated in 2014.

I would recommend that you look at your web analytics to gain more insight into your audiences. Based on my own website stats (which are pretty high-volume), I measured a sample size of over 3 million users in the past year. Of those, 9.8% of users were running IE, and only 3.6% of those were using version 8 or earlier. That effectively translates to 0.35% of all users, or about 11K out of 3 million visitors. These numbers will almost certainly continue to decline over time.

These usage statistics are provided as an example, and they may not be representative of your visitors.

Even though 0.35% is very small statistically, that still translates to 11K people, which is no small number. This ultimately comes down to a judgement call. I certainly wouldn't be building in fallbacks of this nature on new projects, but I wouldn't go out of my way to remove it from old webpages either.

Comment: agreed that it's valuable to consider analytics for usage. In our case we have a lot of users on IE 7/8 because of legacy app support so its a must. Unfortunately, your question does not cover screen readers and I'm hoping someone can also provide some insight on current screen reader support. Thanks!

Comment: Any reasonably modern screen reader (past 4 years or so) won't have a problem with parsing the nav element, and the vast majority of people who use screen readers tend to keep them updated. IMHO, it's the older browsers that you need to worry about. Screen readers are only capable of reading what the browser conveys to them. If you have lots of users on IE 7/8, then yes you should absolutely continue using the role attributes as a fallback.